# Contact Form 7 WP Plugin - Validation

Tags: wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

I've trawled the web for an answer to this issue but can't find a solution.

Is there any way I can completely remove the validation messages (e.g. 'Please fill required field', 'Validation errors occurred') and just leave the red border around the offending textboxes?

In other words, I want Contact Form 7 to still work as normal, but just not show the validation message text; the red border will do.

I've edited the CF7 functions file (includes/functions.php)and commented out sections of the function wpcf7_messages() function, e.g.

```
//'invalid_required' => array(
        //'description' => __( "There is a field that the sender must fill     in", 'wpcf7' ),
        //'default' => __( 'Please fill the required field.', 'wpcf7' )
    //)
```

but nothing works :(

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
//into.append('<span class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">' + message + '</span>');
```

Comment out line 210 in the scripts.js file located here -
plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js.